# Undefined name when using a function annotation

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, annotations

I am trying to express time in terms of `hh:mm`. I know that the colon is telling python to count from hours to minutes but that is not what I want.  Can someone explain a way to correct this mistake of mine?

```
def extract_hours(hours:minutes):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours number, number -> number"""
    return (hours)
```

This is the error I get:

```
NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined
```

Comment: How is your proposed function called? It seems you are *trying* to say `def hr(tm:'hours:minutes'):  return int(tm.split(':')[0])`

Comment: yeah, I have to keep the format as 'hours:minutes' and I tried your solution but it gave me a syntax error for the colon...?

Answer (score 0):

[Function annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) need to be valid [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expressions).  Meaning, you cannot use an undefined name in an annotation or else you will raise a `NameError`.

Instead, you can use a string literal:

```
def extract_hours(hours:'minutes'):
```

This works because string literals are expressions.

Comment: I tried that, and got: TypeError: extract_minutes() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: That is a problem with the caller, not the definition.  Unless of course `extract_hours` is actually supposed to take *two* arguments.  In that case, you need to define it as `def extract_hours(hours, minutes):` with a `,` instead of a `:`.